# Write assembly language program to sort student names according to their grades

Tags: sorting, assembly, x86-16

I want to write a simple assembly language program to sort student names according to their grades.

I am just using:

```
.data
.code
```

I try this bubble sort but this one is only for numbers. How can I add names for the students?

```
.data

array  db 9,6,5,4,3,2,1

count  dw 7

.code

mov cx,count      
dec cx  

nextscan:          
mov bx,cx
mov si,0 

nextcomp:

mov al,array[si]
mov dl,array[si+1]
cmp al,dl

jnc noswap 

mov array[si],dl
mov array[si+1],al

noswap: 
inc si
dec bx
jnz nextcomp

loop nextscan
```

Comment: The English needs to be improved and punctuation needs to be added

Comment: computer works only with numbers. The "names" of students are illusion/interpretation of numbers by all the code you run around it, but inside the CPU even the names are just numbers, CPU doesn't understand or see anything else. So search how strings are encoded in computer first to understand why "name" is just numbers, then you try to understand implementation of `strcmp` function, then try to understand this code + modify it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Long ago, one of the most common way to represent data was with what was called fixed length fields. It wasn't uncommon to find all related data in one place like this;

```
Student:   db    72, 'Marie           '
           db    91, 'Barry           '
           db    83, 'Constantine     '
           db    59, 'Wil-Alexander   '
           db    97, 'Jake            '
           db    89, 'Ceciel          '
```

This is doable, as each of the fields is 16 bytes long and that is the way data used to be constructed in multiples of 2. So the data length was either 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64 and so on. Didn't have to be this way and a lot of times it wasn't, but multiples like that made the code simpler.

Problem is, each time we want to sort, all data has to be moved, so the relational database was born. Here we separate variable data from static.

```
Student:   db    'Marie           '
           db    'Barry           '
           db    'Constantine     '
           db    'Wil-Alexander   '
           db    'Jake            '
           db    'Ceciel          '

Grades:    db    72, 0
           db    91, 1
           db    83, 2
           db    59, 3
           db    97, 4
           db    89, 5
           dw    -1                ; Marks end of list
```

Not only will this be easier to manage in the program, but to add more grades and even grades for the same person is easier. Here is an example of how code would work to do comparisons.

```
            mov     si, Grades
            mov     bl, 0
            push    si

        L0: lodsw
            cmp     ax, -1
            jz      .done

            cmp     [si-4], al
            jae     L0

          .... Exchange Data Here ....

            bts     bx, 0
            jmp     L0

        .done:
            pop     si
            btc     bx, 0
            jc      L0 - 1

            ret
```

After routine has been executed the contents of grades is as follows;

> 61 04 5B 01 59 05 53 02 48 00 3B 00

I do have a working copy of this program tested in DOSBOX and because this is a homework assignment, I'm not going to hand it to you on a silver platter, but 95% of the work is done. All you need to do before handing in is make sure you can explain why `BTS` & `BTC` makes the bubble work and implement something that will exchange data.

If you needed to display this data, you'd need to device a conversion routine from binary -> decimal, but by simply multiplying the index number by 16 associated with each grade and adding the address of `Student` to it, that would give you a pointer to the appropriate name.

Comment: With `mov si, Grades`, there's nothing useful to compare with in `cmp [si-4], al` **on the first iteration**! This code can work if it starts with `mov si, Grades + 2` and under the condition that there's at least 1 student.

Comment: @SepRoland don't know how I missed that, but in the working copy `Grades` is actually pointing to the second element.

Answer (score -1):

Sort pointers to `name, grade` structs, or indices into separate name and grade arrays.

That's one extra level of indirection in the compare, but not in the swap.

Comment: I was going to post this as a comment, but posting answers as comments is frowned upon, and this *is* an answer, albeit a very minimal one.